# Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) Problem 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''=2x+(x^{2}-y')^{2}$

I have tried the Bernoulli method but that still didn't work. There is an extra term of 2x+x^4 which I don't know how to work with.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Is the fact that it is "problem 1" is so important that you give it in your title ?

Comment: It gets even more simple if $u'=y'-x^2$ is used, then $(e^{-u})''=0$.

Comment: Hint: use an auxiliary ODE by setting $u=x^2−y′$ giving a simpler ODE : $2x−u′=u^2$

Answer (score -2):

Ok first let y'=v then y''=v'

$v'=(v-x^{2})^2+2x$

let $v-x^{2}=u$ then $v'=2x+u'$

$2x+u'=u^{2}+2x$

${\int u^{-2} du} = {\int dx}$

$-u^{-1}=x+a$

$u=-(x+a)^{-1}$ , $u=v-x^{2}$ ,$v=y'$

$y'-x^{2}=-(x+a)^{-1}$

${\int dy}={ \int (x^{2} dx-(x+a)^{-1} )dx}$

$y={\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-ln(x+a)+b$